# @expo/vector-icons not loaded when running from subfolder

Tags: react-native, expo, create-react-native-app

I'm trying to use `create-react-native-app` with expo in a monorepo setup. When I start the app from a subfolder `app/` and import `@expo/vector-icons` I get an error that the font family is missing.

```
"fontFamily" 'material' is not a system font and has not been loaded 
through Expo.Font.loadAsync.
```

If I start the app in the main `src/` folder the icons load fine.

I've configured my `rn-cli.config.js` so that the app compiles and runs fine for other dependencies. My project is setup like a monorepo so that I can have multiple native apps in the repo.

```
src/
  MainApp.js
  package.json
  app/App.js 
  app/app.json
  app/package.json
  app/rn-cli.config.js
  ...
```

I've tried a couple things to no avail:

- Install `@expo/vector-icons` in the subfolder package.json
- Setting `"assetExts": ["ttf"]` in the `app.json` file.

My code (mostly from a fresh `creat-react-native-app`):

app/App.js

```
export { default } from "../MainApp";
```

app/app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "sdkVersion": "22.0.0",
    "react": "16.0.0-beta.5"
  }
}
```

app/package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "native": "react-native-scripts start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "expo": "^22.0.0",
    "react-native": "^0.49.0",
    "react-native-scripts": "1.7.0"
  }
}
```

app/rn-cli.config.js

```
const blacklist = require("metro-bundler/src/blacklist");
const path = require("path");

const roots = [process.cwd(), path.resolve(__dirname, "..")];

const config = {
  getProjectRoots: () => roots,

  /**
   * Specify where to look for assets that are referenced using
   * `image!<image_name>`. Asset directories for images referenced using
   * `./<image.extension>` don't require any entry in here.
   */
  getAssetRoots: () => roots,

  /**
   * Returns a regular expression for modules that should be ignored by the
   * packager on a given platform.
   */
  getBlacklistRE: () =>
    blacklist([
      // Ignore the local react-native so that we avoid duplicate modules
      /\/app\/node_modules\/react-native\/.*/
    ])
};

module.exports = config;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-native-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-native-scripts": "1.7.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "native": "cd app && yarn native"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "expo": "^22.0.0",
    "react": "16.0.0-beta.5",
    "react-native": "^0.49.0"
  }
}
```

MainApp.js

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import MaterialIcons from "react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
        <Text>Changes you make will automatically reload.</Text>
        <Text>Shake your phone to open the developer menu.</Text>
        <MaterialIcons name="search" color="black" size={32} />
        <MaterialIcons name="location-searching" color="black" size={32} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the problem was that I had two different expo modules. Getting rid of the one in the subfolder made it work.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty new to react-native, but I had a similar issue, that I solved by not installing the expo Icons at all and using them normally. So in my package.json I have

```
 "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.4.2",
```

and I import fonts like:

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
```

I bet this is no perfect solution, but as expo is just a tool to make things easier, I don´t feel bad doing something that works, instead of using another tool, that complicates things ;)

Answer (score 0):

my expo version is "expo": "^32.0.0". All you need to do is add your font family which support in react-native-vector-icons groups, such as AntDesign, MaterialIcons, FontAwesome etc.

```
import FontAwesomeIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

<FontAwesomeIcon name="circle" size={10} color="#FF6859" style={{ marginLeft: 5 }} />
```

You can also find icons from https://expo.github.io/vector-icons/